# ERROR 1558 (HY000): Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. How do I solve this?

Tags: mariadb

I am on linux mint using XAMPP 8.2.0 (linux version), that has MariaDB  10.4.27. Ran into a problem. I type the following MySQL code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE employee_info(IN p_em_id INT)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM mentorships WHERE mentor_id = p_em_id;
SELECT * FROM mentorships WHERE mentee_id = p_em_id;
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id = p_em_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I get the following error message.

> ERROR 1558 (HY000): Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100425. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error

It tells me to use my_sql upgrade to fix this problem.

But this does not make sense to me. my_sql upgrade is deprecated, so why are they still telling us to use it?

I uninstalled XAMPP in its entirety. Then reinstalled it, hoping it will work. But I am still getting this very SAME error message. Whats going on?

And oh yes, I posted this problem on the XAMPP forum called apachefriends. Sleepy place really. Just one active user. And even he has no clue.

I have looked around in stackexchange for this same error message. One post claims that running mysql_upgrade should do the trick. I tried it but got the following error message.

> The mysql_upgrade client is now deprecated. The actions executed by the upgrade client are now done by the server.
> To upgrade, please start the new MySQL binary with the older data directory. Repairing user tables is done automatically. Restart is not required after upgrade.
> The upgrade process automatically starts on running a new MySQL binary with an older data directory. To avoid accidental upgrades, please use the --upgrade=NONE option with the MySQL binary. The option --upgrade=FORCE is also provided to run the server upgrade sequence on demand.
> It may be possible that the server upgrade fails due to a number of reasons. In that case, the upgrade sequence will run again during the next MySQL server start. If the server upgrade fails repeatedly, the server can be started with the --upgrade=MINIMAL option to start the server without executing the upgrade sequence, thus allowing users to manually rectify the problem.

Whats to be done about this?

Any help will be deeply appreciated. thanks.

Comment: What versions are you using

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using?  What version did you upgrade from?

Comment: no upgrade, nothing of that sort, I uninstalled the slightly older version of XAMPP, and then reinstalled the latest version from https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html
It is XAMPP 8.2.0 for linux. 
Contains MariaDB 10.4.27

Comment: You have not upgraded your (system) databases to your MariaDB version. You must do this.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for the reply. I made a fresh install of the latest XAMPP version, after that I created my trial database. Still I am getting this message. I guess my database is already at the latest version. Or no?

Comment: Not your database but system databases (sys, mysql).

Comment: @Akina thanks for the help. feeling confused. You are suggesting that I upgrade the system mysql database which is different from XAMPP MariaDB, right? Actually, I had uninstalled it. Someone at the apachefriend forum told me that the system SQL is interfering with your MariaDB, so try removing it, which I did. I will now reinstall it then, and tell you how it goes.

Comment: @Akina, till now I thought that MariaDB worked alone. But from your suggestion I get the feeling that system mysql is also involved. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I now have the latest MySQL installed version. 
`root@Dell-Inspiron-5515:/home/umair# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`
`
I restart XAMPP, go to MariaDB command line, throw in the same code and still get the same error. There is one difference though. Read the error message carefully:

`ERROR 1558 (HY000): Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100427.`

previously, it said 'running 100425' and now it says 'running 100427'.  What does this mean?

Comment: Looks like you have installed both MySQL and MariaDB.

Comment: @Akina should I then uninstall MySQL?

Comment: XAMPP consists of MariaDB, PHP and Perl. MySQL is obviously excess.

Comment: @Akina alright, uninstalled MySQL. Still getting the same error with the code mentioned above. The error message says "Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100427". Whats to be done about this?
You suggested that I upgrade system database. Please tell me the steps, I will definitely try it. thanks.

Comment: You have removed one of the problems. Now upgrade system databases up to actual MariaDB version.

Comment: @Akina I am not sure what system database is and how to upgrade it. Anyway, I searched online and it seems to imply upgrading the whole linux system. I did that just now. So the system database that you talk about should now be upgraded. Right? However, when I restart XAMPP and type in the same code into the command line, I still get the same error. Any other ideas to solve this?

Comment: *I am not sure what system database is* I have told this above. *and how to upgrade it.* Search [MariaDB Server Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/documentation/) about this.. Maybe try to install over the same (your current) MariaDB version separately.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for that same problem as follows:

Go to your XAMPP installed path, for my Debian system it is at `/opt/lampp`.

Then there find the `bin` folder and execute `mysql_upgrade -u root -p`.

For my Debian system it is `sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql_upgrade -u root -p`.

[source](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=82715&sid=d6a68ca534bc34374c3a9b3fcc330692)

Answer (score 0):

Run `mariadb-upgrade`.

The comment about `mysql_upgrade` being deprecated relate to MySQL, not MariaDB.

XAMPP calling MariaDB as MySQL in their product seems to be causing more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

After reading so many sites finally found the soultion on https://iqcode.com/code/html/column-count-of-mysqlproc-is-wrong-expected-21-found-20-created-with-mariadb-100108-now-running-100419-please-use-mysql-upgrade-to-fix-this-error-xampp

These are the steps you need to follow (linux/xampp)

- go to terminal and type `/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p`
- after that enter the mysql user password if it worked well then type exit (if it doesn't have password hit enter without typing anything)
- after that type `cd /opt/lampp/bin`
- and now type `sudo ./mysql_upgrade -u root -p` ,
- enter your password and tadam , here is your mysql upgraded

Answer (score -2):

in Mac, go to /Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql

in PC, go to c:\XAMPP\mysql\data

delete the folder that has the same name of your database in question.

This database then, of course, will be gone.

Recreate it, and restore from the sql backup.

Problem is now gone.

Comment: But why would someone do this?

Comment: This is a solution for those who has the sql backup of the database in questions: Why? Because, 1. Most of the solutions provided so far doesn't work. 2. For those case it do work, my method takes less than half the time.